# How can I propose a new meeting time in Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2013

How can I propose a new meeting time in Microsoft Outlook, upon receiving an invitation for a series of meetings? The newly proposed meeting time should affect all occurrences of the series of meetings.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Propose-accept-or-decline-a-new-meeting-time-c041b2c8-fc3c-43b1-979d-3b40463ac0a9?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB claims that in Microsoft Outlook 2016, Outlook 2013, Outlook 2010, or Outlook 2007, one can propose a new meeting time as follows:

> If you receive a meeting request inOutlook for a time when you aren’t
>   available, instead of declining the request, consider proposing a new
>   meeting time. The meeting organizer can accept or decline the change.
>
> 1. In the open meeting request, click Meeting.
> 2. In the Respond group, click Propose New Time.
> 3. When you propose a new time, you tentatively accept the meeting.
>      However, if you click the text Propose New Time (the lower part of the
>      button) you have the additional options to click Decline and Propose
>      New Time.
> 4. Meeting organizers can send meeting requests that restrict the ability
>      to propose alternate meeting times. If the meeting organizer has
>      restricted meeting proposals, the Propose New Time command isn’t
>      available. Also, you can’t propose a new time for meetings in a series
>      — also known as recurring meetings.
> 5. Click a time when all invitees are available.
> 6. Click Propose Time.
> 7. Click Send.
>
> If you are the meeting organizer, proposed meeting time changes are
>   sent to you. You decide whether to change the scheduled meeting time.

However, in the Respond group, I don't see any `Propose New Time`:

[image]

I use Microsoft Outlook 2013 in Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the article you have quoted: "***Also, you can’t propose a new time for meetings in a series — also known as recurring meetings.***" I also see the same behavior on recurring meetings. This is the by design behavior, you cannot propose a new time for a recurring meeting in Outlook.